# is in iphone javascript Enable dispble?

Tags: javascript, iphone

i have one project working greate but in other iphone not working .both are same model with same os. i m thinking i may be of javascript problem . is it so ? how can i Enable disable javascript wih code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not so sure, but assuming your app is running within a browser context, then you either have to enable javascript from the browser settings or otherwise if it's ON then debug your app. A quick check to see whether (client-side) javascript is enabled check whether `alert('js');` works.